# Web Api MVC project/data returning not serializing properties

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Webapi Controller, REST, data exists. I'm not getting it serialized correctly...

InputController:

```
[Route("Input/{guid}")]
    public Input GetInput(string guid)
    {
        var inputs = from input in context.Inputs where input.Guid == guid select input;
        if (inputs.Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        var first = inputs.First();
        return first; // this HAS a valid Input.
    }
```

Model's metadata:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata))]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class Input
{
    private class Metadata
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public double? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When (return first) shows a complete, valid, Input of data...
here's what I get:

```
<Input xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Models" z:Id="i1" />
```

It's empty on serialization - no properties. I've tried removing the IsReference=true (thought I needed due to recursive many-to-many links), however, I get less (without some namespaces).

What am I missing to not get Name, Value, etc?

Answer (score 0):

not sure why it wanted to return nothing - however, the issue was resolved when I removed the whole metadata reference class AND solved the cyclical problem. Too tightly coupled to the data without a mapper.